# Consuming Wcf Service using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, wcf

I have created a WCF Service. It is working fine. When I am consuming it using Java Script, it can not find the Service.

My Java Script Code:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="Service/DataService.svc/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#BtnSendMessage").click(
        function () {
            CallXmlDataService();
        });
    });

    function CallXmlDataService() {        

        var Data_Service = new IDataService();
        var UserName = document.getElementById("TxtName").value;
        var UserEmail = document.getElementById("TxtEmail").value;
        var UserMessage = document.getElementById("TxtMessage").value;
        Data_Service.InsertData(UserName, UserEmail, UserMessage);
        alert("Data Inserted Successfully");
    }
</script>
</head>
```

My Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void InsertData(string Name, string Email, string Message);
}
```

All files are created in the same solution. Check it out:

[image]

My HTML Page:

```
<body>
<table id="TblExport">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="TxtName" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="TxtEmail" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea id="TxtMessage"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="BtnSendMessage" value="SendMessage" /></td>
        <td><label id="LblErrorMessage"></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

When i click on the Send Message button, the console says IDataService is not defined.

[image]

My Web Config file:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="XmlDataApplication.Service.XmlDataApplicationBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="XmlDataApplication.Service.DataService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="XmlDataApplication.Service.XmlDataApplicationBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="XmlDataApplication.Service.IDataService"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: I have checked the code in detail there is no prob with code I think you have missed one of js file in your application

Comment: I think i have attatched all files

Comment: you have to configure end point in your config file see my ans

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure end point in your web.config file I have checked it and it's working fine in my pc.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFJSproxyDemo.Service.WCFJSproxyDemoBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>   
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="WCFJSproxyDemo.Service.DataService">
    <!--<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WCFJSproxyDemo.Service.WCFJSproxyDemoBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFJSproxyDemo.Service.IDemoWCFService">
    </endpoint>-->
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WCFJSproxyDemo.Service.WCFJSproxyDemoBehavior"
             binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFJSproxyDemo.Service.IDataService">
      </endpoint>
  </service> 
</services>
```

Comment: I have put my configuration file. I do not know where is the problem.

Comment: thanks. let me check out your code. Is it necessary that when we are accessing the html page, the service is also running in the background?

Comment: In this application we have inbulit web service so when you run the application service will automatically run.

Comment: in your case, this is running perfectly. But in my case, i am using HTML page and i do know why it is not running..

Comment: @NimitJoshi: no I have take a html page it's also working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54927/discussion-between-dhaval-patel-and-nimit-joshi).